# Why does HCl ionize in water?

Tags: bond

Why does the Hydrogen proton "prefer" to join the $\ce{H2O}$ molecule instead of remaining bonded to the chlorine atom?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chlorine is a very large atom compared to hydrogen, which means the overlap between the hydrogen $1s$-orbital and the chlorine $sp^3$ orbital is poor, which translates into a low bond energy.

Additionally, chlorine is very electronegative, which helps pull the H-Cl bonding pair onto the chlorine atom. The chloride anion solvation in water also plays a big part.

It's simply because it's energetically favourable. Maybe someone knows in greater detail than I do.

Comment: Your answer is already more descriptive than I expected. I was wondering if there was a better answer than simply "being energetically favourable". Saying that water is a stronger base than the chloride ion is just a way to mask that. So is mentioning HOMO/LUMO orbital energies. Of course, all answers boil down to potential energy minimization (which itself boils down to entropy maximization), but the difference is how much *feel* you can get for why it happens, and how much you can extrapolate to other systems from it. Perhaps someone can still find something to add.